# Jquery ajax not submitting form to database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My jquery ajax is not submitting form to my php file. The success alert only alert blank on submit and it won't insert anything to my database. But my php file inserts to database without using ajax.

Here is my code, any idea or new way to do this

This is the AJAX CODE

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
          alert("mannn");
          $("#adduser").submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "adduser_processor.php",
              data: $('#adduser').serialize(),
              success: function(data){
                alert(data);
              }
```

Here is the php code to insert to database

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  //Check if the form is submitted
  $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $gender = $_POST['gender'];
  $about = $_POST['about'];
  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $timeadded = date("Y/m/d, \a\\t G.ia ( l)");
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  // Wanna Clean Values to prevent fro Hackers

  $fullname = cleaninputs($fullname);
  $username = cleaninputs($username);
  $about = cleaninputs($about);
  $number = cleaninputs($number);
  $gender = cleaninputs($gender);
  $password = cleaninputs($password);
  $address = cleaninputs($address);

  $checkuserq = "SELECT username FROM pos_staffs WHERE username = '$username'";
  $exeq = mysqli_query($connection, $checkuserq);
  $numrow = mysqli_num_rows($exeq);
  if ($numrow > 0) {
    $msg = "<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-danger'>Username ($username) Choosen by Another Staff</li>";
    //echo $msg;
    //header("location:addnewuser.php?msg=$msg");
  } else {
      $insertquery = "INSERT INTO pos_staffs(id,fullname,username,password,about,gender,address,date_joined)
      VALUES('','$fullname','$username','$password','$about','$gender','$address','$timeadded')";
      $insertq = mysqli_query($connection, $insertquery);
      if ($insertq) {
        //header("location:addnewuser.php?msg=$msg");
        $msg = "New Staff ($fullname) has being added he can now Login";
        echo $msg;
      } else {
        $msg = "Something Went Wrong";
        echo $msg;
      }
```

But i dont think my php file has an error because it insert normally without error.

Comment: Please post your html form

Comment: Also never under any circumstance store a password in plain text. Use php password hash

Comment: What do you see if you add `print_r($_POST); exit;` at the top of the PHP file? Also notice that you never `echo` anything if the username is already in the DB. You just save the error in `$msg` but do nothing with it.

Comment: Put the echo on the last line then update us, maybe the condition that has been met is the "user already exist"

Comment: thats not the case